# Using rsync and find on remote files

Tags: rsync, backup

REMOTE:

- Dir1
- - DirA
- - DirB
- - - File1
- - - File2
- Dir2

Local:

- Dir1

I want all directories and files in REMOTE Dir1 that are older than 2days to rsync to local directory Dir1 with delete option. Not even certain if I could run it on local and pull from remote, as how would I obtain the list of files? Yes, I have seen some answers but I do not see how this would work.

Comment: Can't you just pull _all_ files over and then delete the old ones locally? That would be much easier. Timestamps are transferred if you use the `--archive` option.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you can guarantee that file names don't contain spaces or other complicating characters you can embed `find` into the `rsync` command. However, my recommendation would be to run the `find` remotely as this avoids any of the aforementioned complications:

```
ssh -n remoteHost find /path/to/source -type f -mtime +2 -print0 |
    rsync --dry-run -av --from0 --files-from - remote host:/ /path/to/target
```

Test, and when you're happy with the set of matched files, remove `--dry-run`